# Javascript Prototypal Inheritance - Truly understanding the concept

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototypal-inheritance

I was looking at this video explanation(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qMO-LTOrJaE) of JS prototypal inheritance.
There's something I don't understand. Let me explain

```js
var Bear = function(type) { //PARENT
  this.type;
  this.hasFur = true;
}

Bear.prototype.kingdom = 'Animalia'; //ASSIGNING TO PARENT'S PROTOTYPE

var Grizzly = function(type) { //CHILD
  this.species = 'Brown Bear';
}

Grizzly.prototype = Object.create(Bear.prototype); //INHERITING FROM PARENT

var grizzly1 = new Grizzly('grizzly');

console.log(grizzly1.hasFur); //prints undefined //members in parent's constructor not accessible
console.log(grizzly1.kingdom); //prints Animalia //however, members in parent's prototype is accessible
```

But as soon as you add the following line to the Grizzly constructor,

```
var Grizzly = function(type){
  Bear.call(this, type); //ADDED
  this.species = 'Brown Bear';
}
```

you're able to access everything from the parent, not just it's prototype

```
console.log(grizzly1.hasFur);  //prints true
console.log(grizzly1.kingdom); //prints Animalia
```

However, inheriting in the below fashion, gives the child access to everything in the parent even without the line //Bear.call(this) in the Child constructor.

```
Grizzly.prototype = new Bear();
```

So it truly inherits everything this way. Can someone explain what's this behavior and why it happens ?

Also what are the different ways of inheriting in JavaScript. Which one is the best to use considering best practices and why.

Comment: With `Grizzly.prototype = new Bear();`, you're actually *calling* the constructor in order to create an object that inherits from `Bear.prototype` and so the new object has all the properties defined in the constructor. With `Object.create(Bear.prototype)`, you're creating an object that inherits from `Bear.prototype` *without* getting the side effects from the constructor. I'd use `Object.create()` because you don't always want the side effects that happen in constructors.

Comment: Your last paragraph is too broad of a question for SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> There's something I don't understand. Let me explain

```js
var Bear = function(type) { //PARENT
  this.type;
  this.hasFur = true;
}

Bear.prototype.kingdom = 'Animalia'; //ASSIGNING TO PARENT'S PROTOTYPE

var Grizzly = function(type) { //CHILD
  this.species = 'Brown Bear';
}

Grizzly.prototype = Object.create(Bear.prototype); //INHERITING FROM PARENT

var grizzly1 = new Grizzly('grizzly');

console.log(grizzly1.hasFur); //prints undefined //members in parent's constructor not accessible
console.log(grizzly1.kingdom); //prints Animalia //however, members in parent's prototype is accessible
```

In the code snippet shared above, `grizzly1.hasFur` is `undefined` as the constructor function for `Bear` is not yet executed. The line `Grizzly.prototype = Object.create(Bear.prototype);` just inherits the parent prototypal methods and properties.

> But as soon as you add the following line to the Grizzly constructor,

```js
var Bear = function(type) { //PARENT
  this.type;
  this.hasFur = true;
}

Bear.prototype.kingdom = 'Animalia'; //ASSIGNING TO PARENT'S PROTOTYPE

var Grizzly = function(type) { //CHILD
  Bear.call(this, type); //ADDED
  this.species = 'Brown Bear';
}

Grizzly.prototype = Object.create(Bear.prototype); //INHERITING FROM PARENT

var grizzly1 = new Grizzly('grizzly');

console.log(grizzly1.hasFur); //prints undefined //members in parent's constructor not accessible
console.log(grizzly1.kingdom);
```

`grizzly1.hasFur` is now `true` because now within the constructor function of `grizzly`, the constructor class for `Bear` is invoked changing its context using a `call`. The `this. hasFur` gets its `true` value assigned in this operation as here due to the changed context, `this` now refers to the instance of `grizzly`.

> However, inheriting in the below fashion, gives the child access to everything in the parent even without the line //Bear.call(this) in the Child constructor.
>   Grizzly.prototype = new Bear();

What happens here is, a new instance of the Bear class is created. Now any instance of the class Bear can have access to the prototypal methods and internal properties defined while instantiating the constructor class i.e. `function Bear`. Now after the instance being created, this gets assigned to the prototypal chain of `Grizzly`. So any new instance of `Grizzly` not only access the internal properties of `Grizzly`, but also behaves as a new instance of the Bear class.

> Also what are the different ways of inheriting in JavaScript

I would definitely suggest you to study design patterns. You can google out different books for it. I loved reading *JavaScript: The Good Parts* and *Learning JavaScript Design Patterns*. You might love some other books for clearing up your fundamentals. There are few countable things in Javascript like these, closures, etc., which needs crystal clear conceptions.

> Which one is the best to use considering best practices and why.

The best practice in prototypal inheritance ,I prefer,is:
In the constructor class say `A`

```
function A () {
   this.privateProp = something;
}
A.prototype.public = something;
```

So see declare only those properties and methods inside the constructor class, which you wanna keep private. Rest keep it exposed in prototype chain.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Very thorough! Taught me some things I didn't know

Comment: Awesome explanation! So in your best practice example, do you suggest
function Parent(){
 this.privateProp = something;
}

Parent.prototype.publicProp = something;

function Child(){
}
Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype); 
var child1 = new Child();

So that child1 has access to only the public props(in prototype) and not the private props in the Parent constructor ?

Comment: Thanks. Yeah its the purpose of the inheritance. You can restrict the child access, as well allow access to parents public property.. :D

Answer (score 2):

Check this out:

```
var Bear = function(type){ //PARENT
  this.type;
  this.hasFur = true;
}

alert(new Bear().hasFur);
```

See how this *does* gives you `true` in the alert box. Think, why is this working, and not for your example?

Thought about it?

It's because in this code:

```
var Bear = function(type){ //PARENT
  this.type;
  this.hasFur = true;
}
```

You're assigning the function to `Bear`, so it's accessible by `new Bear()` not `Bear.prototype`. This will work:

```
Bear.prototype.kingdom = 'Animalia'; //ASSIGNING TO PARENT'S PROTOTYPE

var Grizzly = function(type){ //CHILD
  this.species = 'Brown Bear';
}

Grizzly.prototype = Object.create(new Bear()); // Modified line

var grizzly1 = new Grizzly();

alert(grizzly1.hasFur);  // Prints true now.
alert(grizzly1.kingdom);
```

Comment: Gotcha, but how is 
Grizzly.prototype = Object.create(new Bear()); different from 
Grizzly.prototype = new Bear();