# JavaScript Inheritance assigning a value to constructor

Tags: javascript, inheritance, constructor, prototype

I´m learning javascript OOP and I´m having issues understanding inheritance. Could you explain me why the outcomes from this two codes differ? :

**Code 1**

```
function a(){}

function b(){
    this.uno = "hello"}

b.prototype = new a();

function c(){
    this.dos = "bye"}

c.prototype= new b();

var obj = new c();

console.log(obj.uno);
console.log(obj.dos);
console.log(obj.constructor);
```

**Output 1**

```
hello 
bye
[function: a]
```

**Code 2**

```
function a(){}


function b(){
    this.uno = "hola"}


b.prototype = new a();


function c(){
    this.dos = "bye"}

c.prototype = {constructor:b}

var obj = new c();

console.log(obj.uno);
console.log(obj.dos);
console.log(obj.constructor);
```

**Ouput 2**

```
undefined
bye
[function: b]
```

I truly appreciate any guide on the subject.

Comment: It differs because `new b()` does not return `{constructor:b}`, so it's not the same thing

Comment: The question is: why exactly did you expect them to behave identically? They are clearly different.

Comment: even if you assign an object to its own prototoype it doesnt make sense.

Comment: One of my previous answers on similar topic is http://stackoverflow.com/a/38819813/5102631. It also illustrates a similar kind of problem. @max you can check it too.

Comment: The `constructor` property doesn't have any effect on prototypal inheritance in Javascript, unless your code uses it explicitly. This [question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4012998/6445533) might help.

Comment: Thank you all for your rapid answers, I'll study the posted links to get a better understanding on the subject. Obviously, I still have much to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code snippet

```js
function a() {}

function b() {
  this.uno = "hello"
}

b.prototype = new a();

function c() {
  this.dos = "bye"
}

c.prototype = new b();

var obj = new c();

console.log(obj.uno);
console.log(obj.dos);
console.log(obj.constructor);
```

Lets understand whats happening. When you are doing

> b.prototype = new a();

A new instance of `a` is created and is directly assigned to prototype of `b`. 
So right at this moment if one does
`var obj = new b();`
The `obj.uno` will be equal to `hello`.

Now, when the statement

> c.prototype = new b();

is executed, the obj(a instance of the `b` class) is now assigned to the prototype of `c`. So right at this moment if one does
`var obj = new c();`

- `obj.dos` = `bye` as its assigned in the `c` constructor class.
- `obj.uno = 'hello'` as it was once assinged while instanciating `b` constructor.
- As the constructor property is not re-assigned it will still point to the original parent `a`. So `obj.constructor = function a()`.

---

In the second snippet

```js
function a() {}


function b() {
  this.uno = "hola"
}


b.prototype = new a();


function c() {
  this.dos = "bye"
}

c.prototype = {
  constructor: b
}

var obj = new c();

console.log(obj.uno);
console.log(obj.dos);
console.log(obj.constructor);
```

> c.prototype = {
>         constructor: b
>       }

is not inheriting `b` or its prototype chain. In every constructor`s prototype chain there is a`constructor`property which points to the constructor class. In the avobe statement, it just reassings it to the function`b`.

**UPDATE:**
[Constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor) is a property defined in the prototype chain in any object and as functions are [first-class-objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/705173/what-is-meant-by-first-class-object) in JS, they too have this property inscribed.

So when you execute the above line, its basically changing the c.prototype.constructor value. And nothing else.

Had you been doing this

```
 c.prototype = {
  constructor: 5
}
...
console.log(obj.constructor); // 5.
//Its like setting a value for a property in a JS object.
```

So when you do:

> console.log(obj.constructor);

It points to the newly assigned constructor, i.e. `function b()`.

But as there is no inheritance,

> console.log(obj.uno);

is definitely undefined.

However,

> console.log(obj.dos);

will be `bye` when you are creating a new instance of the function `c`:

> var obj = new c();

Hope this helps to understand JS prototypal inheritance in a better way.

Comment: Thank you very much for your dedicated answer Ayan. I thought the property "constructor" of the prototype object, was responsible for the inheritance of the function class.  So, what do you meant when you said that  **c.prototype = { constructor: b }**  is not inheriting but reassigning?

Comment: Hey @maxfraguas Have updated that part of the answer, giving an example for it. Let me know if it sounds better

Answer (score -1):

Because `new b() !== {constructor:b}` ([as adeneo mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38858754/javascript-inheritance-assigning-a-value-to-constructor#comment65081646_38858754)). The prototype expects [a lot more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype) than just a `{constructor}` property, so just providing an object (literal) with that won't do much.